# how to return nothing when there is no output from database

Tags: php, mysqli

May i know how to return nothing when there is no result from the database? When there is result, it displays just fine but when there is no result, this happens! i have attached an image to show the result when the data is submitted! 
How do i go about on not displaying anything at all if the conditions do not match the result i want?

thank you for your kind assistance!

[Click here for an image of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xygUT.png)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$rap=$_POST['AtRap'];




$percent = (15/100);
$diff = $percent * $rap ;
$a=   $rap - $diff;
$b=   $rap + $diff;
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Max(Shape), Max(Clarity), Max(Colour), Max(Carat), Max(RapNinety), Max(AtRap) FROM Rapaport WHERE (SELECT AtRap BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') AND (Colour='J' and Clarity='VS2' and Shape='Round') LIMIT 1 ") ;

$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Max(Shape), Max(Clarity), Max(Colour), Max(Carat), Max(RapNinety), Max(AtRap) FROM Rapaport WHERE (SELECT AtRap BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') AND (Colour='G' and Clarity='VS1' and Shape='Round') LIMIT 1 ") ;

$query3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Max(Shape), Max(Clarity), Max(Colour), Max(Carat), Max(RapNinety), Max(AtRap) FROM Rapaport WHERE (SELECT AtRap BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') AND (Colour='F' and Clarity='VVS2' and Shape='Round')  LIMIT 1") ;

$query4 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Max(Shape), Max(Clarity), Max(Colour), Max(Carat), Max(RapNinety), Max(AtRap) FROM Rapaport WHERE (SELECT AtRap BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') AND (Colour='D' and Clarity='VVS1' and Shape='Round')  LIMIT 1") ;






$count4 = mysqli_num_fields($query4);
if($count4 == 0){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No Results')</script>";
}else{
    while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query4)) {
        $shape = $row4['Max(Shape)'];
        $clarity = $row4['Max(Clarity)'];
        $colour = $row4['Max(Colour)'];
        $carat = $row4['Max(Carat)'];
        $rap90 = $row4['Max(RapNinety)'];
        $atrap = $row4['Max(AtRap)'];

        $output .= " <br /><br />Shape: <b>$shape</b>  &nbsp;&nbsp; Clarity: $clarity  &nbsp;&nbsp; Colour: $colour &nbsp;&nbsp; Carat: &nbsp;$carat <br /><br /> Price Quote:  <br /><br /> <b>$$rap90 - $$atrap</b> (in SGD)<br /><br /> ";
    }

}

$count3 = mysqli_num_fields($query3);
if($count3 == 0){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No Results')</script>";
}else{    

    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
        $shape = $row3['Max(Shape)'];
        $clarity = $row3['Max(Clarity)'];
        $colour = $row3['Max(Colour)'];
        $carat = $row3['Max(Carat)'];
        $rap90 = $row3['Max(RapNinety)'];
        $atrap = $row3['Max(AtRap)'];

        $output .= " <br /><br />Shape: <b>$shape</b>  &nbsp;&nbsp; Clarity: $clarity  &nbsp;&nbsp; Colour: $colour &nbsp;&nbsp; Carat: &nbsp;$carat <br /><br /> Price Quote:  <br /><br /> <b>$$rap90 - $$atrap</b> (in SGD)<br /><br /> ";
        }

}




$count2 = mysqli_num_fields($query2);
if($count2 == 0){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No Results')</script>";
}else{

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
        $shape = $row2['Max(Shape)'];
        $clarity = $row2['Max(Clarity)'];
        $colour = $row2['Max(Colour)'];
        $carat = $row2['Max(Carat)'];
        $rap90 = $row2['Max(RapNinety)'];
        $atrap = $row2['Max(AtRap)'];


        $output .= " <br /><br />Shape: <b>$shape</b>  &nbsp;&nbsp; Clarity: $clarity  &nbsp;&nbsp; Colour: $colour &nbsp;&nbsp; Carat: &nbsp;$carat <br /><br /> Price Quote:  <br /><br /> <b>$$rap90 - $$atrap</b> (in SGD)<br /><br /> ";
    }

}

$count = mysqli_num_fields($query);
if($count == 0){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No Results')</script>";

}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $shape = $row['Max(Shape)'];
        $clarity = $row['Max(Clarity)'];
        $colour = $row['Max(Colour)'];
        $carat = $row['Max(Carat)'];
        $rap90 = $row['Max(RapNinety)'];
        $atrap = $row['Max(AtRap)'];

        $output .= " <br /><br />Shape: <b>$shape</b>  &nbsp;&nbsp; Clarity: $clarity  &nbsp;&nbsp; Colour: $colour &nbsp;&nbsp; Carat: &nbsp;$carat <br /><br /> Price Quote:  <br /><br /> <b>$$rap90 - $$atrap</b> (in SGD)<br /><br /> ";
    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the number of columns using `mysqli_num_fields`.

Use `mysqli_num_rows` to get the the number of `rows`.

Comment: what i meant was to display blank, as in not display anything when there is no result, sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0):

You're using mysqli_num_fields which returns the number of columns of result even if the table is empty. Use mysqli_num_rows instead which returns the number of rows of output.

Example: If a table has 5 columns and no data inside.

mysqli_num_fields() returns 5.

mysqli_num_rows() returns 0.

That's why you're getting the output like that.

Here in the below code, if there is no result, $count will be zero and will execute the if part of code. And if there's data it executes the else part.

Try using this piece of code in every if...else of your code.

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No Results')</script>";

}else{
    //Rest of code 
}
```